# Create autonomous TOC from a ReStructuredText Document

Tags: python, django, markup, restructuredtext, docutils

I am writing a blog in `Django` and I want to compose my posts with `ReStructuredText`. I am using [django-markup](https://github.com/bartTC/django-markup) to convert the text to HTML which works perfectly fine.

Additionally, I want to create a **table of content** out of that text (my blog post).
For this purpose I have created a template tag.

My template looks like the following:

```
[...]
{{ blog.content|rst_toc }}
<hr />
{{ blog.content|apply_markup:article.markup }}
[...]
```

`tags.py`:

```
import docutils
from docutils import core

@register.filter
def rst_toc(text):
doctree = core.publish_doctree(text)

for section in doctree.traverse(docutils.nodes.section):
    title = section.next_node(docutils.nodes.Titular)
    if title:
        print(title)
return 'TOC'
```

My main problem here is that this snippet is missing the document title.

```
=
1
=   
One

2
# 
Two


3
-   
Three
```

returns `2, 3` not `1, 2, 3`

Any further thoughts would be appreciated especially to the fact that I am publishing the `doctree` twice. In `|rst_toc` and `|apply_markup:article`.

Comment: The reStructuredText markup is incorrect for sections. The over/underlines must be the same length as the section name. See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections

Comment: Thanks for your reply I changed it but my question still persists.